# Cannot resolve class TextView, ImageView, LinearLayout,

Tags: java, android

When I want to create TextView, ImageView and ... in my file xml, everything turns red and tag style appears instead of height and width the I have to copy and paste any features manually. The app will run although everything is red, like the attached photo.
I also have cleared the cache through  File ->Invalidate caches
but the problem still exists.

I'm new to android and need some help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50mOE.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ja7nd.jpg)

Comment: could you please post the text of the actual xml file

Comment: Invalidate caches & restart

Comment: Please check parent class tag is closed OR not.

Comment: Please post the complete xml of the layout file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

upgrade your Gradle version.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1'
```

and sync the project.

after completing this process you face the same issue then goto
File ->Invalidate caches & restart and select Invalidate & restart.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade your Gradle wrapper

distributionUrl=http://gradle.sankuai.com/android/gradle/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip

Note:https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#4-2-0